# Designing simple cell renderer for Nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus, tablecellrenderer

I have a simple-ish cell renderer which is composed of a few `JLabel`s (the renderer itself extends `JPanel`) and I'm trying to get it to render sensibly in the Nimbus look and feel. Basically what is happening  is that in the *lighter* rows (as Nimbus has *alternate row coloring*), my specific cell renderer is using the table background color (which is much darker than both lighter and the darker *row* colors). In my renderer I do:

```
if (isSelected) {
    setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground);
}
else {
    setBackground(table.getBackground);
}
```

If I comment this whole block of code out then then all my rows are in the darker *row* color (not the table background, but not in alternate colors either). I'm not sure I even understand what can be going on! How is the above snippet of code producing cells with different background colors at all? Is the `table.getBackground` color changing between invocations of my method?

I've tried using this snippet of code:

```
Color alternateColor = sun.swing.DefaultLookup.getColor(
                         peer, 
                         peer.getUI, 
                         "Table.alternateRowColor");
if (alternateColor != null && row % 2 == 0)
    setBackground(alternateColor);
```

Which is in the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` class. And it doesn't seem to have any affect at all. Has anyone got custom cell renderers working with Nimbus?

**EDIT**: If anyone is interested, this turned out to be a problem with *Scala* table cell renderers, as I was actually using Scala, not Java. The accepted answer below works just fine in a Java program. Separate question filed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326763/table-cell-renderer-using-nimbus-and-scala).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first piece of code if fine.I think you have to use `UIManager.getColor("Table.alternateRowColor")` for alternate rows and table.getBackground() otherwise. For selected row use table.getSelectionBackground(). So your code might look like

```
if (isSelected) {
    setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
}
else {
    if ( row % 2 == 0 ) {
       setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.alternateRowColor"));
    } else { 
       setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make sure that your panel is opaque and the labels are transparent.

Here is a good link to Nimbus UI defaults:
http://www.duncanjauncey.com/java/ui/uimanager/UIDefaults_Java1.6.0_11_Windows_2000_5.0_Nimbus.html

Comment: Yes - this is *exactly* what I tried and it didn't work. However, I'm actually using Scala, not Java, so I decided to knock up a quick test case in Java and it worked. So thanks. Unfortunately I have no idea why it doesn't work in Scala!

Comment: Even though I don't know much about Scala, I don't see a reason why it should not work. Swing is Swing, even in Scala.

Comment: It's acutally `if ( row % 2 == 1 ) {`.

Comment: depends what row you consider to be the alternate ;)